# How to average list of dicts?

Tags: python

Consider a list of dicts

```
a = {(0,1) : 10, (2,9): 20}
b = {(0,1) : 20, (2,9): 60, (3,3): 15}
list_of_dicts = [a,b]
```

How can I obtain an average `c` from this such that

```
c = {(0,1) : 15, (2,9): 40, (3,3):15}
```

A related question is [Get average value from list of dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027792/get-average-value-from-list-of-dictionary), but the solution doesn't account for key `(3,3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to first aggregate all items from all dicts, and then calculate the average for each key:

```
def average(l):
    return sum(l) / len(l)

collected = {}
for d in list_of_dicts:
    for key in d:
        if key in collected:
            collected[key].append(d[key])
        else:
            collected[key] = [d[key]]

# collected = {(0, 1): [10, 20], (2, 9): [20, 60], (3, 3): [15]}

for key in collected:
    collected[key] = average(collected[key])

# collected = {(0, 1): 15.0, (2, 9): 40.0, (3, 3): 15.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chain` from `itertools` to combine both dictionaries. Use `dict.setdefault(key,[]).append()` to create a key:value pair. Then all you need to do is find the average.

The code to do this is:

```
from itertools import chain
a = {(0,1) : 10, (2,9): 20}
b = {(0,1) : 20, (2,9): 60, (3,3): 15}
c = {}
temp = {}
[temp.setdefault(k,[]).append(v) for k,v in chain(a.items(), b.items())]

c = {k:sum(v)/len(v) for k,v in temp.items()}
print (c)
```

Output of this will be:

```
{(0, 1): 15.0, (2, 9): 40.0, (3, 3): 15.0}
```